# Use android.app.Service and SensorEventListener while screen is off (Android 2.1)

Tags: android

Hi: I'm using Android 2.1 on a HTC Nexus One. I want to collect sensor data while the device is turned off. 
By using android.app.Service this works well while the app is in the background but stops working when the display is turned off by the hardware button.

Is there a possibility to collect sensor data while the display is turned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dre: WakeLocks are alrerady activated.

The solution is by using Android 2.2 (Froyo). Even when the display is turned off, the device can log the sensors.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you hold a partial or higher wake lock, turning off the display can allow the CPU to fall asleep.

See the [android.os.PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) documentation for information on how to use wake locks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to do this myself but try reading [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) it may be of some help. You could try setting up each situation and specify that services remain running. Although if other services suck up more resources your application will be more likely killed by the linux Kernel over time. As I said I've never had to do this myself, but I think that would work.